# How to get the key as soon as value gets changed in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my firebase structure like this

[image: Firebase Structure]

I want to get a the key/number as soon as status becomes 1.

I tried..

```
//Listen for number
var ref = firebase.database().ref("games/" + gameId + "/numbers");

ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('1').on("value", function(snapshot)
{
  snapshot.forEach((function(child){ 
    console.log(child.key);
  }));
});
```

But every time status gets updated i am getting every number with the status = 1.
I want just the last updated number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `child_changed` instead of `value`. It will only return single value in which child will be changed so we will get key directly by `snapshot.key`.

```
//Listen for number
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("games/" + gameId + "/numbers");

    ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('1').on("child_changed", function(snapshot)
    {
        console.log(snapshot.key);
    });
```

I think, it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you listen for the `value` event, you get a snapshot with all matching data each time.

If you want to get more granular notifications, you can listen for `child_*` events. For example to hear when a node status gets set to one, you can listen for `child_added`:

```
ref.orderByChild('status').equalTo('1').on("child_added", function(snapshot)
{
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

You'll note that I also remove the `forEach`. Since `child_` events fire for each individual child, you no longer need the loop.

If you find it hard to figure out which `child_` event to listen to, I find it easiest to think of the query as a "view" on the data. When a child node's status is set to 1, it enters the view, so it is `child_added`. When a child node's status is set to another value, it leaves the view, so it'd fire `child_removed`.